# Android Remove file with DDMS

Tags: android, ddms

I need to remove a file from the /data/data folder my app added. I am looking at the file with the DDMS in Eclipse.

If DDMS can't , how would I delete it otherwise?

Comment: Can you explain the problem more precisely: what does it mean "If DDMS can't" ? What exactly happens when you try to delete it via DDMS. 
Alternatively to DDMS you can always use the command line "adb shell"; adb is in the tool folder of your Android SDK. You can then use it just like you use a linux shell, browse folders, delete files (if you have the permissions to it).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
adb shell rm /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer works of course but the question asked how to do it in DDMS, so here it is:

1. Ensure your emulator is running and go to DDMS perspective.
2. In the Devices window select your emulator
3. Then go to Window-->Show View-->File Explorer
4. Select the file and click the red minus in the top right of File Explorer to delete the file off the device or emulator.

Comment: I have this issue as well. When I select a directory, the - is not enabled.

Comment: I've noticed that when multiple files are selected, the - is not enabled as well. Is this by design to "protect us from ourselves"? Annoying if so.